# List of relations, union and intersections of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I would like to know if these exercises about relations are right. I will appreciate any help.

**1. Write a list of all relations from the set $A$ to the set $B$ where $A=\{\alpha,\beta\}$ and $B=\{x\}$.**

### $R=\{(\alpha,x),(\beta,x)\}$

**2. Given the relations $R_1=\{(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)\}$ and $R_2=\{(a,b),(1,2),(c,d),(3,4)\}$. Find the relation $R_1∩R_2$ and $R_1∪R_2$.**

### $R_1∩R_2=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$

### $R_1∪R_2=\{(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(a,b),(c,d)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the second question is correct.

For the first one, recall that a relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A \times B$. Since in your case, $A$ has two elements and $B$ has one element, the set $A \times B$ has two elements, and the set of subsets of $A \times B$ has $2^2 = 4$ elements. Thus you should find four relations, but you just found one of them...

Comment: So are $(x,\alpha)$ and $(x,\beta)$  are too in $R$?

Comment: I guess you mean that $R_1 = \{(\alpha,x), (\beta,x)\}$, $R_2 = \{(\alpha,x)\}$ and $R_3 = \{(\beta,x)\}$ are three relations from $A$ to $B$. So what is the fourth one?

Comment: So is $R_4=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is it!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. <3

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you have the possibility to accept it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/tour .